# How do i use regex to remove all text before a the second (or third, or forth) instance of a _ and remove all text before the next _

Tags: regexp-replace

I want to track in Google Data Studio the amount of users coming to my site as a result of different campaigns. I have created URLs with tracking code embedded. The URLs looks like

**Input:**

1. [www.sitename.com.au/landing-page?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=fruit_apples_kids](http://www.sitename.com.au/landing-page?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=fruit_apples_kids)
2. [www.sitename.com.au/landing-page?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=fruit_banana_adults](http://www.sitename.com.au/landing-page?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=fruit_banana_adults)

The utm_campaign in the URLs above is an internal naming protocol to help reporting. It’s made up of three parts campaign group (fruit), campaign type (apples/banana), campaign focus (kids/adults)

I want to set-up a table in GA so I can run a report on all campaigns that have driven users to my site with a breakdown of the various campaigns. In the table I want to display the data in columns. I was planning to use regex_replace to look at the campaign and to split the tracking code down in the table by the (_). What is the best way to write that regex?

**Desired Output**

[Campaign Group    Campaign Type    Campaign Focus    Users
fruit             apples           kids              15
fruit             banana           adults            7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4mr0.png)

I have been trying to complete this using regex_replace but cant get it to work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have made some edits to try and help clarify. i hope this makes more sense. Sorry - first time using.

Comment: Not helping.  Please just show the complete input, along with the output you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have tried again. i hope this helps